# Is it correct? mom will let me go, will give me permission or other?

Tags: grammar

Which is the best:

> Will you come here again?
> **Yes, If mom would let me...**      (A)
> We are sure that mum will let you go
>
> Will you come here again?
> **Yes, if mom will give me permission...**     (B)
> We are sure your mom will let you go
>
> Will you come here again?
> **Yes, if mom lets me to go...**     (C)
> We are sure your mom will let you go

or maybe other?

Comment: Q: *Will* you come here again? A: Either: Yes, if mom *will* let me. / Or Yes, if mom lets me.

Comment: Your first version carries a significantly different implication (by using the "hypothetical" modal ***would***, you imply you think probably she ***wouldn't***). The second is credible, but not as likely as the third (except it should be *If mom lets me go* - no *to*). Some might say the future tense in #2 places more focus on a specific occasion in the future when you will be seeking permission, but I think most native speakers would rarely if ever consider such nuances, or notice them being used by others.

Comment: The third line in each choice is a little problematic.  It's unlikely that anyone would refer to another person's mother as "mum", as that would refer to the speaker's own mother.  You might say, "We are sure that *your* mum will let you go."  There would be an exception if the speaker of the third line were mocking the speaker of the second, for instance if both were grown men and one had to ask permission of his mother for some reason.

Comment: @JasonPatterson or if they're siblings...

Comment: This question could be better written, but I don't understand why it has close votes.

Answer (score 1):

Will you come again?

> **If mom lets me**
>   **If mom gives me permission**

Those are the two I would use.

You can say, "If mom lets me go," but you would **not** say, "If mom lets me <strike>to</strike> go."